# get ItemTouchHelper object from RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, itemtouchhelper

In my code I attach an `ItemTouchHelper` to `RecyclerView` in this way:

```
ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(simpleItemTouchCallback);
itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(mRecyclerView);
```

`simpleItemTouchCallbak` is an `ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback` instance. Above code will be called multiple times, however I want to attach `ItemTouchHelper` only once. I know that I can keep a reference to it or use a boolean flag, but I want to know is there any way to get touch helper reference form `RecyclerView` or its `LayoutManager`?

Comment: Nope. You'll have to track that yourself.